# Ngram doesn't works like configureted

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am working using hibernate search annotations, but there is also an Elasticsearch implementation. My tokenizer does not split according to its configurations. In particular I expect the string to be divided with a minimum of 3 characters. But it ignores my configuration and continues to split [image]with a minimum of one. What am I doing wrong?

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "EdgeNgram",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class,
                params = {
                        @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "3"),
                        @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "20")})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your difference between minGramSize and maxGramSize is quite honestly, huge. It seems Elasticsearch ignores your settings and uses the default (1,2).

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) of the nGramTokenizer says that there is a maximum allowed difference.

According to the [index module documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html), this value defaults to 1.

I suspect that Elasticsearch rejects the definition you provide because of this. You can try setting the `index.max_ngram_diff` on your index settings.

Comment: maybe you re right. But where I must configure this properties?I must configure all with hibernate search annotation.

Comment: @ChristianScarselli In Hibernate Search 5, your only solution to configure that kind of setting would be to register [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-templates.html) on your Elasticsearch cluster before Hibernate Search creates the indexes. In the next major version of Search (6), we will provide a better solution. No release date yet.

Comment: can you give me more details?

Comment: I can, but you could also read the documentation I gave you and ask a more specific question ?

Comment: I must to define a new template every time I reset the indexes?and this configuration that I set up, is also ignored by Lucene? Is this configuration OK for Lucene?

Comment: @ChristianScarselli Templates remain on cluster level. So unless you start a new cluster, you are fine with just defining a template once - just make sure new indices (names) match the template. Lucene is (codewise) behind Elasticsearch, so I'd say either both will accept the configuration or none will.

Comment: @yrodiere meanwhile hibernate search modules are available in version 6:
Does the API now provide any way to configure the max_ngram_diff ?
I cannot find anything in the documentation.
Would be great if you can provide a link.

Comment: @aminator Custom server-side settings in Hibernate Search will be coming in Hibernate Search 6.1: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3934 . It wasn't released yet (and we're finishing another major feature before we release the first alpha). But you can get some idea of what it will look like here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/pull/2438/files#diff-664de639de1194498d0ece4565afa623893432052bb56f7bb93caac356dc9e69R894